# Always getting values from first form. What's wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a webpage where there are several forms. It looks like [image: this].

When "Create" is clicked an ajax script checks the fields for illegal values in the first form, where the Create button belongs to. That's fine.

But when the "Save" button is clicked, it still checks fields from the first form, and not the form where the Save button belongs to.

My Ajax looks like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //    $('form').submit(function() {
    $('form').live('submit', function(){

    var title = $('#title').val();

        ...
```

Is it here the problem could be? I have tried with the commented code, but that doesn't work either.

Any ideas where the problem could be?

Comment: how about showing the offending code around the save button. This code doesn't offer many options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('#title').val();` means "Get the value of the **one and only** input that has the id *title*".

If you have violated the spec and have multiple elements with the same id, then browsers will generally recover from the error by returning the first such element.

You should probably change the id to something like: idOfForm_title (so that your `<label>` elements still work)

And then use: `this.elements.title.value` where `title` is the value of the **name** attribute (and `this` automatically resolves to the form on which the submit event fires).

Comment: I think you found the problem. =) I am going to try that right away. Will return shortly =)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should give your forms a `class`, like `class="create"` for the first / create form and then `class="edit"` for the second / edit form.

Then you can amend your jQuery to look like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // only work with the 'create' form
    $('form.create').live('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // stop the form's default action

        // the rest of your code
    });

    // only work with the 'edit' form(s)
    $('form.edit').live('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(e); // stop the form's default action

        // the rest of your code
    });
});
```

Comment: @Sandra Schlichting: Depending on the scripting language you use (assuming PHP), then yes. You'd could use jQuery to isolate the `.edit` form elements, `serialize` the input values and then pass it through to a server-side file where it could perform validation / updates on records in the database, etc, finally passing a success or failure notice back to jQuery which could then display a message to the user.